# Is there a way to point on servant-server 0.15 that is not yet on the last haskell LTS?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, servant

I would like to use the version 0.15 instead of the the one available on the last LTS (12.22), usually I'm adding this in stack.yaml :

```
extra-deps :
  - git: git@github.com:haskell-servant/servant.git
    commit: e3e5d2b23057c2c3409e5e210b613527baf3b77d
```

But they use multiple projects in the same repo so it does not work :-( :

The current entry points to

```
/Users/nhenin/dev/gsdFlow/.stack-work/downloaded/6krbU6UwORFF/ but no .cabal or package.yaml file could be found there.
```

Do you know how I could use it ?

Comment: I think [within a week LTS13 will be released](https://www.stackage.org/blog/2018/11/upcoming-lts-13-ghc-8-6-2) which might possibly include Servant 0.15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is specify sub directories in the repository containing the project:

```
extra-deps:
  - git: git@github.com:haskell-servant/servant.git
    commit: e3e5d2b23057c2c3409e5e210b613527baf3 
    subdirs:
    - servant
```

if you needed `servant-pipes` from the repository as well, for instance, you'd also include it in the list:

```
...
    subdirs:
    - servant
    - servant-pipes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `subdirs` subfield to tell stack what project you want to add. See https://github.com/eta-lang/dhall-to-etlas/blob/master/stack.yaml f.e.